# How to fill a list with json array of strings in jasper reports?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

Let's assume we have this JSON:

```
{
    "header" : "some header",
    "strings": [
                    "foo",
                    "bar",
                    "baz"
                ]
}
```

And we want to display it in jasper report - header as a textfield, and the array in a list.

This is the report, which has access the array, but does not display all the elements of it - only first of them appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="100" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="6c570f43-054a-44a9-a9b1-ba4cf2cdcf86">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="json-sample"/>
    <subDataset name="ListDataSet" uuid="fb812d2a-cb63-473c-b7d3-149977476dd0">
        <field name="val" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="strings.*"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="header" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="header"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[header]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="strings" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="strings"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[strings]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d98a55eb-ebbd-4cdd-8fa2-ae052b124aaa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{header}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="450" height="30" uuid="887dc258-2eac-4492-ae69-f9b2ffd1faee">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.CONTENTS.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ListDataSet" uuid="1316cfd7-fe59-440f-a155-501914c00056">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})).subDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="4ee2d6b3-c681-433f-a170-4bb31697de58"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{val}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

This is how the result looks like:

[image: result]

What is wrong with the report?

Answer (score 2):

Your fields could be updated a little:

- $F{header} => `java.lang.String`
- $F{strings} => `java.util.List` - this makes it possible to use this field as the datasource for a subcomponent.

Then when you pass in the Datasource, just pass in the list:

- `new JRBeanCollectionDatasource($F{strings})`
- or `new JRBeanArrayDatasource($F{strings})`

For you List data set I would just:

- $F{_THIS} => `java.lang.String` - I'm not sure if `val` works well, but I know for sure that `_THIS` works (both 5.2 and 6.3)

I'll try to post the JRXML if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass child array by using this library

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})).subDataSource("strings")
```

Here report code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="100" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="6c570f43-054a-44a9-a9b1-ba4cf2cdcf86">
    <subDataset name="ListDataSet" uuid="fb812d2a-cb63-473c-b7d3-149977476dd0">
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[strings]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="val" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="."/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[.]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="header" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="header"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[header]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="strings" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="strings"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[strings]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d98a55eb-ebbd-4cdd-8fa2-ae052b124aaa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{header}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="450" height="30" uuid="887dc258-2eac-4492-ae69-f9b2ffd1faee">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.CONTENTS.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ListDataSet" uuid="0904f194-ec62-41b4-96ab-8fe46a40166c">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})).subDataSource("strings")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="4ee2d6b3-c681-433f-a170-4bb31697de58"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{val}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).